# Create and Android project in Eclipse and duplicate it easily

Tags: android, eclipse, duplicates

What is the best way to create an Android project and duplicate it?
I would like to have projects that inherit a class that is responsible for the configurations and the base project to bug fixes and improvements.

Another problem that comes to mind is the design that some projects may change, for that matter should be able to add in my project resource folder that inherits the resources to change.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the duplication of project: you can easily copy-paste the whole project's structure and then from Eclipse you can do `New Project` -> `Android Project` -> `create project from existing source`.

What you are actually asking about, if I am not wrong, is Android Library project. This is a project that you can use to add on the source of other projects. You can read about android library projects [here](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2011/03/03/android-library-projects/) and in the linked page [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html).

Comment: I am using my base as a library project and is what I wanted. Just one more thing, if I have in base project an configuration class that is used by the application, how do I overwrite values in this class for use ​​in the other projects that I copy?

Comment: Can't you use polymorphism for that? You can define a getter method that gets overwritten in the derived applications.

Comment: The problem is that my library has Activities, classes, resources, etc. ..
And the project that use the library, just wanted to take one class to configure.
If I created a class that inherits from the configuration class, and created a getter overwritten, it will never have access to this class, go to the library class.

Answer (score 0):

I would use github fork system for inheriting projects and files. Take a look at [github](http://github.com), create an account. Moreover, there is [google code](http://code.google.com) and [tortoise svn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)  alternative.

Comment: I like this idea. Just one question, is it easy to fix bugs in a project and copy it to the rest?
My idea is to lose the least possible time

Comment: I'm not sure but Tortoise SVN has apply patch function for google code alternative. You can take a look at that